# Something went wrong while saving this configuration Warning: is_file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string

Tags: magento2

I have been trying to figure out how to crete two stores, e.g. one for UK and one for Germany. Each should have its own base currency which products are priced (just like amazon)

i have been told this maybe possible, so created an additional site, web and view (so now I have 2 of each).

Next issues are how to change the default "store" currency for the second on (not found this option yet), and how to actually access the second store.  I tried using a subdomain, e.g. "second_store.mydomain.com" rather than www.mystore.com. I set this URL in the "Base URL" in stores->settings->configuration->general->web, choosing the second store from the dropdown. But when I hit this URL, I get a 404 (I set the DNS to the same ip).

My prefered option would be to have www.mydomain.com/store1.  I am guessing this "Add Store Code to Urls" does this.  However, when I set this to yes, I get this error:

"Something went wrong while saving this configuration: Warning: is_file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given in /var/sites/j/mystore.store/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 545"

I am using php 7.1, magento 2.3.0

I do not know if the command worked. I have not found a way yet to access the second website.  Certainly www.mystore.com/xx where xx is the second site code does not work (404)

Any suggestions, or has someone written a guide?